# How is the size of the particles is determined?

Tags: particle-physics

What is the size of atomic and subatomic particles, like proton, neutron, photon etc? Is it defined based on some quantum characterics as *de Broglie* wavelength or *Compton* wavelength?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size is determined by the [scattering cross section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_cross-section).

Classically one could measure the size of a leaf ( for example) by measuring its shadow from a light source, if the geometrical distances were known.

For elementary particles it is  more complicated because the projectile and the target interact quantum mechanically but still we can get an estimate of the size of a proton when seen by photons, or by muons  or by neutrinos by using the appropriate parameters of the interactions involved.

We get "average sizes" because nothing is sharp in quantum mechanics and it depends on the momentum transfer during the interaction in a non trivial way, but we do get a good measurement of its size, and distribution of quarks within the protons, neutrons  and pions by measuring [form factors](http://www.phy.anl.gov/theory/PHYTI09/PHYTI09_fichiers/ArringtonQCD09.pdf).

Neutrinos, photons and electrons are deduced/assumed  to be point particles of dimension 0, in these scattering experiments.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the (correct) [method that anna suggests](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/53035/520) is to measure the momentum distribution of the sub components and apply a Fourier transform. As a matter of experimental difficulty these kinds of studies usually come later then direct cross-section measurements, but they provide a different kind of data and can throw a new light on the particles probed.