# Roundness of electrons

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, charge, elementary-particles, point-particles

I have seen articles online discussing the roundness of electrons. This goes a bit against my understanding of electrons as elementary point like particles. How can a point have a shape? What does roundness mean in this context?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119732/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24001/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277565/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/264676/2451 and links therein.